# Why is my query not returning any results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm brand new to elasticsearch and have been failing getting this to work the way I expect. I know for a fact that this record exists, and if I use `"query": "kill"` it will show up as `"Kill Bill, Vol. 1"`

However, the way it's written below, it returns 0 hits. 

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working the way I expect?

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 5,
    "_source": ["_id", "title"],
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "kill bill",
                    "type": "best_fields",
                    "fields": [
                        "title^1",
                        "director",
                        "description"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "user_id": "1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the mappings:

```
{
    "items": {
        "mappings": {
            "external": {
                "properties": {
                    "director": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "user_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the item as it's stored:

```
{
    "_index": "items",
    "_type": "external",
    "_id": "23",
    "_version": 136,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "description": "A former assassin, known simply as The Bride (Uma Thurman), wakes from a coma four years after her jealous ex-lover Bill (David Carradine) attempts to murder her on her wedding day. Fueled by an insatiable desire for revenge, she vows to get even with every person who contributed to the loss of her unborn child, her entire wedding party, and four years of her life. After devising a hit list, The Bride sets off on her quest, enduring unspeakable injury and unscrupulous enemies.",
        "title": "Kill Bill, Vol.1",
        "director": "Quentin Tarantino"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide mappings by any chance? Have you tried temporary removing `"type": "best_fields"`? Perhaps it's causing harm.

Comment: `best_fields` is the [default value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types), so removing it should not change the result. As @EvaldasBuinauskas suggested, seeing your mapping would greatly help.

Comment: Are you trying both queries with same filter?

Comment: @Val I've added the mappings

Comment: @Undefined_variable even if I completely remove the filter I still get 0 hits.

Comment: Also note that you have `directors` in your mapping and `director` in your query. Probably not the issue but just mentioning. Can you share your sample "Kill Bill" document?

Comment: @Val That was a typo, but thanks for catching it. Added the document.

Comment: Ok, I just created that index locally with your mapping, I indexed the sample document and your query (unaltered) does return that document properly. Maybe wipe your index and recreate it from scratch, it should work.

Comment: @Val unbelievable... that was it. must have been a corrupted index. Thanks for taking the time to check that for me!